# Hide quotes from a title

Tags: jquery, string, hide, quotes

I need to suppress quotes from "mytitleinaquote" and don't know how to do it.

Here's a sample:

```
<p class="cff-post-text"><span class="cff-text" data-color=""><b style="font-size: 22px">"mytitleinaquote"</b><br> <br> The text begins here...</span></p>
```

This is what I tried:

```
jQuery ( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery("span.cff-text").each(function() {
    var x = jQuery(this).text();
    x = x.replace('/"', '');
  });
});
```

Sure not working, how to improve the code?
Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `b` as your selector than:

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  $("span.cff-text b").text((i, v) => v.replace(/"/g, ''));
  
});
```

```html
<p class="cff-post-text"><span class="cff-text" data-color=""><b style="font-size: 22px">"mytitleinaquote"</b><br> <br> The text begins here...</span></p>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

PS: don't use inline `style`. Makes the markup clumbersome, and in some circumstances even raise an *unsafe-inline* flag. Instead, **use CSS**:

```
.cff-post-text b {font-size: 22px;}
```

PS2. To **prevent flashing content** and forcing the browser to relayout and repaint due to changes in DOM *content* - I would consider to remove those quotes **server-side**, before the page arrives to the browser.

Comment: Thank for your help, It's working... I put bold style inline with jQuery, because CSS can't modify the style in a Facebook RSS flux.